# how to remove strings in pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a column of pandas have data like following string

> ```
> =COUNTIF(sheet1!AS:AS,"YES-ZH")+COUNTIF(sheet1!AU:AU,"YES-ZH")+COUNTIF(sheet1!AR:AR,"YES-ZH")+COUNTIF(sheet1!AT:AT,"YES-ZH")
> ```

i'm trying to use `apply(lambda s: s.replace())` to remove all no necessary strings one by one. 
but there a problem, the `COUNTIF` formula it's not fixed 4 sets. it's random
therefore it cause to the excel sheet column range like `sheet1!AT:AT` are random too.

i also use

> ```
> Pattern3 = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]+)(\\:)([a-zA-Z]+)')
> xxx['formula']=xxx['formula'].apply(lambda s: s.replace(  Pattern3.search(s).group(1)  ,''))
> ```

but it can only remove 1st one.

hope the result of the  `xxx['formula']` can be

```
sheet1,YES-ZH,sheet1,YES-ZH,sheet1,YES-ZH,sheet1,YES-ZH
```

Comment: Your example uses Pattern3 and Pattern2 - is that a typo? If not, that may be the problem.

Comment: yes it's typo here. it's not impact the problem , i will revise.